# Setting BooleanToVisibilityConverter to true depending on selected combo box value

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I need to add some logic to my code that will set the BooleanToVisibilityConverter to true or false depending on a selected value from a XAML combo box in my MVVM model. To complicate matters I actually have 2 combo boxes. The list displayed in combo box 2 depends on what value is selected in combo box 1

Combo box 1 XAML

```
<ComboBox Margin="103,6,0,24" 
     x:Name="FirstOne" 
     Grid.Column="1" 
     DisplayMemberPath="SetCriteria" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding CriteriaList}" 
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCriteriaLists, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Combo box 1, code behind

```
public void SearchViewModel()
    {
        this.CriteriaList = new ObservableCollection<SearchCriteriaList> 
        {
            new SearchCriteriaList {SetCriteria = "Date Range"},
            new SearchCriteriaList {SetCriteria = "Gateway"},
            new SearchCriteriaList {SetCriteria = "Direction"}
        };

              this.OperatorList = new ObservableCollection<SearchOperatorLists>();        
        }
```

Combo box 2 XAML

```
 <ComboBox Margin="103,41,1,40" 
                          x:Name="SecondOne" 
                          Grid.Column="1" 
                          Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                          DisplayMemberPath="OperatorName" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding OperatorList}"/>
```

Combo box 2, code behind

```
private readonly List<SearchOperatorLists> dateOperatorList = new List<SearchOperatorLists>
    {
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Today"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Between"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Last Month"}
    };

    private readonly List<SearchOperatorLists> gatewayOperatorList = new List<SearchOperatorLists>
    {
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "CCSUK"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "MCP"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "CNS"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Email"}
    };

    private readonly List<SearchOperatorLists> directionOperatorList = new List<SearchOperatorLists>
    {
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "In"},
        new SearchOperatorLists {OperatorName = "Out"}
    };

    private SearchCriteriaList selectedCriteriaList;
```

OK so using an onPropertyChanged event whenever a value is selected in the FirstOne combo box (Date Range, Gateway or Direction) combo box 2 display the corresponding list (dateOperatorList, gatewayOperatorList, directionOperatorList)

My requirement is to capture a value in combo box 2, say "Between" and then set my BooleanToVisibilityConverter to true. Which in this case will display 2 date pickers.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: That's not what a BooleanToVisibilityConverter is for.  Create your own converter, or create the appropriate state property in the view model.

Answer (score 1):

Rather use an object model where your primary item (first combo) has a `Children` property which contains the items for the second `Combobox`.

This would then make your second `Combobox`'s `Binding` as:

```
<ComboBox Margin="103,41,1,40" 
                      x:Name="SecondOne" 
                      Grid.Column="1" 
                      Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="OperatorName" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCriteriaLists.Children}"/>
```

Much simpler and less of a maintenance issue in the long run if the lists of dependent objects change.